# SNMP Custom MIB's, How to send non-Windows data over SNMP

Tags: windows, snmp, mib, oid

I want to send my own values over SNMP. So I have a program that will generate data. I want this data to be available over SNMP. How do I do this? Any advice will be appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: There is a lot (a _lot_) to SNMP, so I would first point you to the documentation for the [WinSNMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, tell you to do a lot of reading of about how SNMP works, and also suggest that, sorry, this isn't the place to ask for generic advice. Once you've written some SNMP code, you can ask here about its errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the Windows SNMP agent by writing your own extensions,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9024/How-to-develop-a-SNMP-extension-agent-DLL

Comment: I followed the tutorial, but I get no data. I may have installed the .dll incorectly. But all the values in the document are hard coded? I want the reference my own data that will be running on the device